# H2 db 'Chunk no longer exists' error

Tags: java, database, h2, h2db

When I'm trying to add a new row to db "INSERT INTO invited_users VALUES('id', user_name')"

I'm getting this error:

```
General error: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Chunk 2089 no longer exists [1.4.181/9]"
```

Probably it's some problems with db, because when I tried to add the same row to a new db - error disappeared.

**Update Nov 20, 2014**

Good news! I contacted developers of H2 db and find out that they will fix that bug in the next release.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/i_GHXExjotc

**Update Dec 6, 2014**

A simple workaround is to disable the MVStore by appending ";mv_store=false" to the database URL.

**But**, this trick will not work, if you need the old db. It creates new database, with .h2.db extension instead of .mv.db

**To overcome this** you need to create SQL script of your old database ".mv.db" (with Recover tool), and then run this script using "runscript ...".

Comment: Possibly interesting: https://www.mail-archive.com/h2-database@googlegroups.com/msg16976.html and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/i1YwSTG8CS8

Comment: @JimGarrison yeah, thanks. I already read this

Comment: Give [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @philipxy That's all. It's a complete example, I'm just trying to add row to H2 db "INSERT INTO invited_users VALUES('id', 'user_name')".
I doing that via web interface http://127.0.1.1:8082

Comment: Sounds like a database problem, not an application problem. Which version of h2db are you using?

Comment: @jtoberon lastest  1.4.182

Answer (score 5):

In version 1.4.182, there is probably something  wrong with the mechanism that detects when a chunk is no longer referenced. Currently, this is `reference counting` garbage collection: by counting live
pages and live space. If this reaches zero, a chunk can be overwritten after 45 seconds.

A simple workaround is to use the `page store` storage mechanism instead of `mv_store` by changing the database connection to use `mv_store=false` as a mitigation.

MV_STORE option is automatically enabled since version [1.4.177 Beta](http://www.h2database.com/html/changelog.html).

> By default, the MV_STORE option is enabled, so it is using the new
>   MVStore storage. The MVCC setting is by default set to the same values
>   as the MV_STORE setting, so it is also enabled by default. For
>   testing, both settings can be disabled by appending ";MV_STORE=FALSE"
>   and/or ";MVCC=FALSE" to the database URL.

Comment: @PierAlexandreBouchard no man, this workaround not worked for me. It creates new database, but I need the old one.

Comment: @PierAlexandreBouchard Is it possible to overcome this?

Comment: It is not possible for you to duplicates the rows from the old to the new database?

Comment: @PierAlexandreBouchard it suits me, how to do this?

Comment: Read for the SCRIPT statement here: http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#script

Comment: You should be able to use a SQL query.

Comment: @PierAlexandreBouchard I tried method you suggested above and it almost worked for me, in my db ~108000 rows, Recover tool created SQL script with ~74000 rows and then stopped with the same error 'Chunk no longer exists'. Looking forward to the new version of h2db. Thanks for you help)